# Is there an operator valued mandelbrot set?

Tags: operator-theory, dynamical-systems, fractal-analysis

Here's a thing I literally dreamed of last night :D

Let $B=\mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))$, or for that matter some other unital C*-algebra. Let
$M_B\subset B$ be the set of operators $c\in B$ for which the sequence defined by $a_0=0,\ a_{n+1}=a_n^2+c$ is bounded.

What can one say about $M_B$? Has there been research about it? Is it a frightening looking infinite dimensional analogue of the classical Mandelbrot set? I mean, what certainly is true is that for any projection $p$ and for any element $\lambda$ of the classical mandelbrot set, $\lambda p$ must be in $M_B$, hence $M_B$ contains infiniteley many copies of $M_\mathbb{C}$, but what can one say about operators not of this form?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Addition: for a commutative unital C*-algebra $B=C(X)$ for a compact Hausdorff $X$ we can see that $f\in M_B$ if (and persumably only if) $f(X)=\sigma(f)\subset M$, where $M$ is the classical Mandelbrot set. So it may be true that this also holds for the general case, i.e. an element $c\in B$ is in $M_B$ iff its spectrum is a subset of the Mandelbrot set, although I'd have no idea how tobprove that..

Comment: Why should we care about the Mandelbrojt set?

Comment: Why shouldn't we?